# can not resolve method super arguments for ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android

I have following code snippet ! I get error on the super call to ArrayAdapter constructor. I am not able to figure out why it is not taking list of maps in constructor call to super !

Error : can not resolve method

```
super(android.App.activity, int, java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>>)
```

---

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<List<Map<String,String>>> {
    private Context m_Context;
    private String[] m_ItemName;
    private Integer[] m_ImgId;

    public ListAdapter(Activity context, List<Map<String,String>> myList) {
        super(context, R.layout.org_list_single_item, myList);
        this.m_Context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(m_Context).inflate(R.layout.org_list_single_item, parent, false);

            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_dtl);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            txtTitle.setText(m_ItemName[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(m_ImgId[position]);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: what type has `R.layout.org_list_single_item`?

Comment: it is a layout file which consists of a text and image view to hold my data ! XML file in layout folder !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `ArrayAdapter<T>`, the third parameter should be of type `List<T>` objects.
So in your case : `List<List<Map<String,String>>>`

Comment: Yes it works fine, but i could not understand why it is like this ? I thought that List<T> means List <Map<String,String>>. I mean T could be any object right ? Also, I just want to pass a list of maps to my constructor. how do I achieve that. This solution works but it seems now that I pass list of list of maps ! I am stumped now !

Comment: Maybe you want to extend ArrayAdapter<Map<String,String>> then

Comment: I thought that extend ArrayAdapter<List<T>> means that we can extend from ArrayAdapter<List<Map<String,String>>> too ? If however, I do change it to as you mentioned it does not give any compilation error in the IDE. But still question remains for me that if i extend from ArrayAdapter with list of maps then i should be able to pass list of maps in the super constructor call as an argument. I am pretty confused now how this is working !

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to help you more. Maybe you should look at this documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html and at the ArrayAdapter API. If you extend ArrayAdapter<T>, the constructor takes a List<T>. It means that if you extend ArrayAdapter<AnyClass> the constructor takes a List<AnyClass> as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The code works fine now, but i hope i will be able to find the reason behind this !